# How to access Text Score MongoDB $text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, text-search

I was successful in running $text search using Mongoose in Node.js code. Here is the code I used:

```
Model.find( 
     { $text : { $search : "FindThisString"}},
     { score : {$meta : "textScore"}}
  )
 .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore'}})
 .exec(function(err, results) {
     _.each(results, function(item) {
        //console.log(item);
        console.log(item._id);
        console.log(item.score);
     });
});
```

When I console log the entire document, I can see the "score" field in on the console, but "item.score" prints as "undefined".

How can I access the score created by MongoDB in the returned results?

Comment: can you show your item? How it looks when you do `console.log(item)`

Comment: { _id: 57bd960dd6499fef9dad4f01, cName: 'XYZ', cAddress: ' ',  __v: 0, score: 1.0073315117131936, contentSection: [], ..... }

Comment: "score" is a field returned in the results. I can access all other fields of the document and process/print them - except the score.

Answer (score 5):

Alright I figured it out... what needs to be done as follows:

console.log(item._doc.score);

That will do the trick!

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find much information regarding this.

Comment: Thank you for following up, this was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

Model.find() returns a [mongoose Document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) instead a plain Javascript object. I guess that when you try to access to the property "score", some kind of validation occurs and because you don't have it in you schema, it returns `undefined`.

In my opinion, the best way to get the value of `item.score`, is by converting the mongoose Document object into a plain Javascript object.

For that purpose you can make Model.find() to return a plain object by using the `{ lean: true }` option (see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) and [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) for more information):

```
Model.find( 
  { $text : { $search : "FindThisString"}},
  { score : {$meta : "textScore"}},
  { lean: true }
)
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore'}})
.then( (result) => {
  result.forEach(item => console.log(item.score));
});
```

Or (in case you need the mongoose Document for other purposes) you can get the plain javascript object by using [Document.prototype.toObject()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-toObject) method:

```
Model.find( 
  { $text : { $search : "FindThisString"}},
  { score : {$meta : "textScore"}}
)
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore'}})
.then( (result) => {
  result.forEach(itemDocument => {
    const item = itemDocument.toObject();
    console.log(item.score);
  });
});
```